# Oracle 12c - conditional where

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a query like such:

```
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
              INTO v_count 
              FROM some_table 
             WHERE some_column = v_some_data
               AND other_col = v_other_data
```

I want to use the clause "`AND other_col = v_other_data`" ONLY if `v_other_date != 'A'`.

Is this the best way?

```
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
          INTO v_count 
          FROM some_table 
         WHERE some_column = v_some_data
           AND other_col = case when v_other_data = 'A'
                                then other_col
                                else v_other_date
                           end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `case` in `where` clauses. You can always replace that with boolean logic

```
WHERE some_column = v_some_data
AND (v_other_date = 'A' OR other_col = v_other_data)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using `case` in `where` clause?

Comment: Not really, but many users seem to have a problem appying it right and IMO boolean logic looks easier to read than a `case`.

Comment: In your solution can't we just have `v_other_date = 'A' OR other_col = v_other_data`, because if `v_other_date = 'A'` is false(not equal) then we don't need to check it again?